Python Azure functions in the same Function app require different packages versions
We have a project that requires multiple azure functions. The first plan was to host all the functions on the same function app using the consumption plan. From the Microsoft documentation I understood that functions on the same function app share the same execution process which mean they need to use the same packages version, am I right ?
I have seen an option for .NET functions to run as isolated functions but this is not possible for Python runtime.
Is the only solution for functions with different requirements versions is to separate them into different function apps ?
I am wondering also, as functions in the same function app share the same execution process, if it is worth hosting more than one function in the same app. The reason is that, as the same process is used, once a function is trigerred, all other functions code is compiled and stored in memory even if they weren't triggered, this makes cost higher than if the functions were splitted into different apps.
Your feedbacks would be very appreciated

Can you share the code which you have tried?


Is the only solution for functions with different requirements versions is to separate them into different function apps ?

Yes, when multiple functions are hosted in the same Azure Function App, they share the same execution environment, it can limit different functions need different package versions, particularly since Python doesn't support isolated process execution in Azure Functions.
If there are functions called function_a and function_b
they are have different packages need to run the function.
function_a:
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
from azure.functions import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from azure.functions.decorators import FunctionApp, http_trigger

app = FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="FunctionB")
@app.route(route="FunctionB")
def main(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    data = {'Column1': [4, 5, 6]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return HttpResponse(f"Dataframe in Function B:\n{df}")


requirements.txt:
pandas==1.1.5
azure-functions

function_b:
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
from azure.functions import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from azure.functions.decorators import FunctionApp, http_trigger

app = FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="FunctionB")
@app.route(route="FunctionB")
def main(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    data = {'Column1': [4, 5, 6]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return HttpResponse(f"Dataframe in Function B:\n{df}")

requirements.txt:
pandas==1.3.3
azure-functions

To install requirements by using command pip install -r requirements.txt.
Deploy each function into separate function apps into azure portal.
if i deploy both functions in single function app, it leads to package versions mismatch.
Each Function App will independently handle its dependencies, there is no conflict between different versions of pandas.
